# Microunaut HTTP 403 after authentication

Tags: micronaut

I have 2 micronaut services: `users` and `products` and a Zuul Gateway in front.

I can loggin (`users`) and make *HTTP GET* requests (`products`), but when I try to do a *HTTP POST* or *PATCH* I got a **HTTP 403**.

**users/application.yaml**

```
security:
  enabled: true 
  endpoints:
    login:
      enabled: true 
    oauth:
      enabled: true
  token:
    jwt:
      enabled: true
      signatures:
        secret:
          generator:
            secret: DB4A...
    writer:
      header:
        enabled: true
        headerName: "Authorization"
        prefix: "Bearer "
    propagation:
      enabled: true
      service-id-regex: "products|users"
```

**products/application.yaml**

```
security:
  enabled: true 
  token:
    jwt:
      enabled: true
      signatures:
        secret:
          validation:
            secret: DB4A...
    writer:
      header:
        enabled: true
        headerName: "Authorization"
        prefix: "Bearer "
    propagation:
      enabled: true
      service-id-regex: "products|user"
```

**works HTTP 200**

```
@Secured({"ADMIN"})
@Get("/{id}")
public HttpResponse<?> getProduct(String id)
{
... // OK
}
```

**Forbidden HTTP 403**

```
@Secured({"ADMIN"})
@Post("/products")
public HttpResponse<?> update(@Body List<Product> products)
{
... // FORBIDDEN
}
```

Someone have any idea?

`micronaut.version 1.3.0`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Configuring `maven-compiler-plugin` properly fix the bad compilation.

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <release>11</release>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>-parameters</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">
          <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-security-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
          </path>
          <path>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>test-compile</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.10</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
              </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a Bug in `Eclipse`+`Maven`+`Annotation Processing` doesn't works. After generate the Micronaut inner classes the first time, the `Build Project` or `Build All` execution from Eclipse does not run Annotation Processing again. To fix that we have to run maven.

To Micronaut works in Eclipse you have to run the Maven command by `Run as -> Maven Build` or command line:

```
mvn clean compile
```

or

```
mvn clean test-compile
```